# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:

Tags: php, pdo

i saw other SO links with same error, but none worked for my case.

I am trying to upload an image to the folder "user_images" and save the image path in DB column "user_Pic" using MySQL PDO.

**db file**

```
try{
        $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_HOST};dbname={$DB_NAME}",$DB_USER,$DB_PASS);
        $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
```

**code**

```
if(!isset($errMSG))
        {
            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_users(userPic) VALUES(:upic)');

            $stmt->bindParam(':upic',$userpic); // error in this line

            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                $successMSG = "new record succesfully inserted ...";
                header("refresh:5;index.php"); // redirects image view page after 5 seconds.
            }
            else
            {
                $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
            }
        }
```

**error** :

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 
'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for 

key 'userEmail'' in /var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site3/addnew.php:73 Stack trace: #0 

/var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site3/addnew.php(73): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}

thrown in /var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site3/addnew.php on line 73
```

**complete code :**

```
<?php

    $DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    $DB_USER = 'root';
    $DB_PASS = 'Outthinking123@';
    $DB_NAME = 'designer3';

    try{
        $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_HOST};dbname={$DB_NAME}",$DB_USER,$DB_PASS);
        $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>

<?php

    error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE ); // avoid notice

    //require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
    {



        $imgFile = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
        $tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize = $_FILES['user_image']['size'];



         if(empty($imgFile)){
            $errMSG = "Please Select Image File.";
        }
        else
        {
            $upload_dir = 'user_images/'; // upload directory

            $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

            // valid image extensions
            $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions

            // rename uploading image
            $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;

            // allow valid image file formats
            if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){           
                // Check file size '5MB'
                if($imgSize < 5000000)              {
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);
                }
                else{
                    $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                }
            }
            else{
                $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";        
            }
        }


        // if no error occured, continue ....
        if(!isset($errMSG))
        {
            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_users(userPic) VALUES(:upic)');

            $stmt->bindParam(':upic',$userpic);

            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                $successMSG = "new record succesfully inserted ...";
                header("refresh:5;index.php"); // redirects image view page after 5 seconds.
            }
            else
            {
                $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
            }
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Upload, Insert, Update, Delete an Image using PHP MySQL - Coding Cage</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.codingcage.com" title='Programming Blog'>Coding Cage</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/CRUD">CRUD</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/PDO">PDO</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.codingcage.com/search/label/jQuery">jQuery</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">


    <div class="page-header">
        <h1 class="h2">add new user. <a class="btn btn-default" href="index.php"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> &nbsp; view all </a></h1>
    </div>


    <?php
    if(isset($errMSG)){
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <strong><?php echo $errMSG; ?></strong>
            </div>
            <?php
    }
    else if(isset($successMSG)){
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
              <strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <?php echo $successMSG; ?></strong>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>   

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">

    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">



    <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Profile Img.</label></td>
        <td><input class="input-group" type="file" name="user_image" accept="image/*" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" name="btnsave" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> &nbsp; save
        </button>
        </td>
    </tr>

    </table>

</form>



<div class="alert alert-info">
    <strong>tutorial link !</strong> <a href="http://www.codingcage.com/2016/02/upload-insert-update-delete-image-using.html">Coding Cage</a>!
</div>



</div>






<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the `tbl_users` by any chance have a column `userEmail` that needs a unique value? I'm thinking it does because that is what the error message tells you...

Comment: @jeroen I must be tired today...

Comment: @Mike It can also be pretty late depending on where you are ;-)

Comment: @jeroen 6:30 am actually

Comment: You should read the error message, it tells you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @jeroen table contains `userEmail` that should be unique, but i am trying with new email id only....

Comment: thanks a lot @Your Common Sense , i will never forget you in my life.....

Comment: You are not adding any email address and it seems you have already done that once so the unique value of an empty string already exists and cannot be added again in another row.

Comment: @jeroen thats true, i am not trying to add any email , okay i will try to remove `userEmail` from `unique_value`

Comment: That is probably not the solution, how would you know with what user the newly inserted image belongs? More likely you need an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`.

Comment: @jeroen okay than i will try to login with email and try to upload image.......

Comment: please tell why downvotes, so that i can correct it, i am an idiot in php..... still learning.....